# Ordering Events using Semaphores in C

Tags: c, semaphore

`I am trying to create a program which correctly orders events using multiple threads in C, but I'm struggling to implement semaphores properly. Whenever I compile and run the program, the events seem to happen in random order - what am I doing wrong to implement semaphores?

I have four events written as void functions which call a helper function with a sleep call, and these four event functions are ordered in an array in the main function.

```
// Declaration of semaphore array to syncrhonize events
sem_t s[4];
```

```
void make_event(const char *t, int finish) { 
  if (!finish) {
    printf("%text!\n", t);
  }
  else {
    printf("%s finishing event\n", t);
  }
  sleep(2);
}
```

```
void *event1(void *vargp) {
  sem_wait(&s[0]); 
  make_event("text", 0);
  sem_post(&s[0]);
  return NULL;
}
```

^ there are three other events just like this, but accessing s[1], s[2] and s[3]

Snippet in my main() function:

```
  // Initialized semaphores (0 for threads, 1 for initial value)
  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    sem_init(&s[i], 0 , 1);
  }
```

I also destroy my semaphores at the end.`

Comment: Where is the threading? Where is there any ordering of things?

Comment: Why is `event1` posting `s[0]`? That's the semaphore that makes `event1` run, and it already ran! You need `event1` to do something to `s[1]` to make `event2` run.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I tried calling wait on s[1] in event1 after the make_event() call to get event2 to run, but that doesn't seem to work. Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @LouisRollo Why would `event1` wait for `s[1]`? You want `event1` to *post* `s[1]` so that `event2` can run, right? To make event 2 run after event 1, event 1 has to post the semaphore that event 2 waits for.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I tried that, but still not getting the correct ordering of event1 > event2 > event3 > event4. Each event has a call structure like this: sem_wait(&s1) / make_event() / sem_post(&s2). For the first event should I post s[0], wait on s[0], and post s[1] for the next event?

Comment: @pm100 I have a for loop creating 4 threads and another joining them using pthread_create and pthread_join. The correct order is event1 > event2 >event3 >event4, but as it stands the program does not run them in order; which is what I'm trying to correct using semaphores.

Comment: @LouisRollo Can you show us the code that's supposed to work? The code in the question doesn't make sense because it posts the wrong semaphore.